# Vaildation Form Failed

Tags: php, forms

After I tested the form by clicking the submit button (shown on http://deafmagic.com/tourist-register.php) to check the validation and it showed a blank page. Im not sure what Im doing wrong with the scripts. The red * dot next to the textfields are required to be filled. I only tested one or two textfields to see if it works before I do the rest of the textfields. Thank you!

HTML (form):

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="_sendTouristapplicant.php">
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h1 style="color:#FFFF00;">ATTENTION!!!<br />THIS REGISTRATION IS FOR <br />TOURIST APPLICANT ONLY!!!</h1><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h1>World Deaf Magicians Festival Chicago 2014</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><span xml:lang="EN-US">October 26 – November 1, 2014</span>
    <br /><br /><strong>Tourist Applicant ONLY</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="230" align="right" valign="top">First Name: <font style="color:red;">*</font> </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_1" type="text" size="33" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">Surname (Family Name): <font style="color:red;">*</font> </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_2" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">Street Address: </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_3" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">City: <input name="fieldnm_4" type="text" size="24" /> State: <input name="fieldnm_5" type="text" size="2" /> Country: <font style="color:red;">*</font> <select id="countries" name="countries">
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">Postal / Zip Code: </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_7" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top">Email address <font style="color:red;">*</font>: </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_8" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right">Phone Number:  </td>
    <td>OOVOO: <input name="oovoo" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td>SKYPE: <input name="skype" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top">Fax: </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_10" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top" class="txtForm">In Case of Emergency - <br />
  Contact Telephone Number: </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="fieldnm_11" type="text" size="33" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">Age Group: <font style="color:red;">*</font> 
                <input name="fieldnm_12" type="radio" value="Junior age (7 to 17)" />Junior age (7 to 17)<input name="fieldnm_12" type="radio" value="Adult age (18 to 54)" />Adult age (18 to 54)<input name="fieldnm_12" type="radio" value="Merlin (over 55)" />Merlin (over 55)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">Deaf, Hard of Hearing or Hearing? <br />
    Deaf <input name="deafHH" type="radio" value="Deaf" /> Hard of Hearing <input name="deafHH" type="radio" value="Hard of Hearing" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">Hotel Room to be shared with (Magician, assistant or other person):<br />
    <textarea name="fieldnm_21" cols="80" rows="5">Names:</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#ff0000">I agree to abide to the Contest and Festival Organizers’ Rules. I confirm that I am a Deaf Magician.<br />Yes <input name="agree" type="radio" value="Agreed" /> No <input name="agree" type="radio" value="Disagreed" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><br /><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php ob_start();
$fromemail="Tourist Applicant"; // change here if you want
//$toemail="ff@hotmail.com";   // change here if you want
$sub="Tourist Applicant from Deaf Magic";          // change here if you want


//If form was submitted  
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {  
    $errormsg = ""; //Initialize errors  
    if ($_POST[fieldnm_1]){  
        $fieldnm_1 = $_POST[fieldnm_1]; //If title was entered  
    }  
    else{  
        $errormsg = "Please enter your first name.";  
    }  
    if ($_POST[fieldnm_2]){  
        $fieldnm_2 = $_POST[fieldnm_2]; //If comment was entered  
    }  
    else{  
        if ($errormsg){ //If there is already an error, add next error  
            $errormsg = "Please enter your surname.";  
        } 
    }  
}     
if ($title && $textentry){ 
//Redirect to Thank you page 
   header("Location: thanks.html");   
}  

////// do not change in following
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
$fieldnm_1=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_1']));  
$fieldnm_2=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_2']));  
$fieldnm_3=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_3']));  
$fieldnm_4=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_4']));
$fieldnm_5=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_5']));  
$countries=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['countries']));  
$fieldnm_7=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_7']));  
$fieldnm_8=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_8']));
$fieldnm_9=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_9']));  
$fieldnm_10=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_10']));
$fieldnm_11=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_11']));  
$fieldnm_12=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_12']));  
$deafHH=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['deafHH']));  
$fieldnm_21=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_21']));

$agree=str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['agree']));

$contentmsg=stripslashes("<br><b><font style=color:#CC3300>$sub</font></b><br>
<table width=800 border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1 bgcolor=#CCCCCC>

<tr>
  <td width=600 align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>First Name:</b> </td>
  <td width=200 align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Surname:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Street Address:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>City:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>State:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Country:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$countries</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Postal / Zip Code:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_7</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Email address:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Age Group:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td><B>Phone Number:</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>OOVOO:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$oovoo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Skype:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$skype</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Fax:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>In Case of Emergency - <br />Contact Telephone Number:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_11</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td><B>Age Group:</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Age Group:</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align=right valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF><B>Hotel Room to be shared with (Magician, assistant or other person)</b> </td>
  <td align=left valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$fieldnm_21</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=2 align=center valign=top bgcolor=#FF0000><B><font color=#ffffff>I agree to abide to the Contest and Festival Organizers’ Rules. I confirm that I am a Deaf Magician:</font></b> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td colspan=2 align=center valign=top bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$agree</td>
</tr>
</table>
");

////
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0
";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
";

$from=$fromemail;

$headers .= "From: ".$from." 
";

@mail($toemail,$sub,$contentmsg,$headers);
}               
?>
```

Comment: I see who you are doing this for. I will rewrite this code correctly and submit it back on this page tonight. Please email me if you need any help.... ffrinfo at yahoo

Answer (score 0):

First change all
 `$fieldnm_1 = $_POST[fieldnm_1];`

to:

`$fieldnm_1 = $_POST['fieldnm_1'];`

Meaning... You need a single quotes inside the `$_POST[''];`

Comment: Please, note, what without '' fieldnm_1 is treated as a constant, which is, of course, not set at all. This practice is discouraged in PHP 4 and deprecated since PHP 5. OP my be getting a lot of warnings when running the script

Comment: It can not be defined as constant, because constants can not change.

Comment: I talked about array indexes

Comment: I wasn't talking about array indexes

Answer (score 0):

You started output buffering with

```
ob_start();
```

But I can't see where you finally output the collected data. If you don't - this explains the blank page.

This

```
str_replace ( array("\n"), array("<br>"),trim($_REQUEST['fieldnm_1']))
```

could be replaced with

```
nl2br($_REQUEST['fieldnm_1']);
```

I recommend to change errors from string to array.

Redirect condition is better to be changed to

```
if (count($errormsg) == 0){ 
//Redirect to Thank you page 
   header("Location: thanks.html");   
}  


//If form was submitted  
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {  
    $errormsg = array(); //Initialize errors  
    if (strlen(trim($_POST['fieldnm_1']))){  
        $title = $_POST['fieldnm_1']; //If title was entered  
    }  
    else{  
        $errormsg[] = "Please enter your first name.";  
    }  
    if (strlen(trim($_POST['fieldnm_2']))){  
        $textentry = $_POST['fieldnm_2']; //If comment was entered  
    }  
    else{  
        $errormsg[] = "Please enter your surname.";  
    }  
}
```

If you want to output errors on the page - use `implode("<br>", $errors)` instead of $errors

Comment: It worked as it went through, but it ignored the blank textfields. It did not validate them.

Comment: Then, let's change approach a bit. First, check the length of input, with trailing spaces and newlines removed. Second, before redirecting to thankyou page, instead of checking what everything is set, let's check what there were no errors. I think, you will not like to redirect user if there are some errors in data validation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It still didnt validate the blank textfields, it just went straight to the thankyou page and Im not sure where to put the implode("<br>", $errors). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You also want to check whether $_POST is submitted at all. It's also better to check variables with isset. Also, you need single quotes in POST. Like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {  
$errormsg = ""; //Initialize errors  
if (isset($_POST['fieldnm_1'])){  
    $fieldnm_1 = $_POST['fieldnm_1']; //If title was entered  
}  

if (isset($title) && isset($textentry)){ 
//Redirect to Thank you page 
   header("Location: thanks.html");   
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

This is the "tourist-register.php" entire page:

Please upload this to your site and tell me if all form values are like you want them. if so I will then write the processor for you. And to be sure.. all you want this form to do is email to you and show the customer a thankyou page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to Deaf Magic!</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* copy */
.copy { font-size:14px; color:#FFFFFF; padding-top:250px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:20px;}
.copy h1 {font-size:18px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}

/* Front large images */
img.front-image { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
/* Container */
.container { margin-left:510px; background-image:url(images/internal_topbg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:900px; height:auto;}
/* navigational buttons */
.button_wrapper {width:900px; margin-left:510px; margin-top:550px;}
.buttons { display: inline; }
.button-image { padding-left: 10px;}
.yellow-buttons { width:600px; margin-left:680px; margin-top:20px; }
/* footer image */
.footer-bg {margin-left:510px; margin-top:50px; background-image:url(images/internal_bottombg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:900px; height:284px; }
div.divider{ width:720px;background-color:#222;font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;border-radius:10px;
padding:4px 10px;margin-top:10px;}
div.agree{ width:720px;background-color:#FF0000;font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold;border-radius:10px;
padding:4px 10px;margin-top:10px;}
div.form{ width:720px;}
div.form label{display:inline-block;  width:250px;font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:16px;}
div.form input, textarea, select {display:inline-block;margin-left:20px; }
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000" link="#1690e9" alink="#1690e9" vlink="#1690e9">
<div class="container">
<div class="copy">

<div align="center">
<h1 style="color:#FFFF00;">ATTENTION!!!<br />
THIS REGISTRATION IS FOR <br />
TOURIST APPLICANT ONLY!!!</h1><br />
<h1>World Deaf Magicians Festival Chicago 2014</h1>
<span xml:lang="EN-US">October 26 – November 1, 2014</span><br /><br />
<strong>Tourist Applicant ONLY</strong>
</div><br><br>

<div class="form" >

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="tourist_email.php">

<label><font style="color:red;">*</font>Firstname:</label><input name="first_name" type="text" size="45" autofocus /><br>

<label><font style="color:red;">*</font>Surname(Family Name):</label><input name="last_name" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>Street Address:</label><input name="street" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>City:</label><input name="city" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>State:</label><input name="state" type="text" size="2" />

Zip Code:<input name="zip" type="text" size="10" /><br>

<label><font style="color:red;">*</font>Country:</label><select name="countries">
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad">Chad</option>
<option value="Chile">Chile</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo">Congo</option>
<option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
<option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
<option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
<option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
<option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Greece">Greece</option>
<option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
<option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="Guam">Guam</option>
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
<option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
<option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
<option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="Israel">Israel</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
<option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
<option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
<option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macao">Macao</option>
<option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
<option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali">Mali</option>
<option value="Malta">Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
<option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
<option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
<option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
<option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
<option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
<option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger">Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="Niue">Niue</option>
<option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option value="Norway">Norway</option>
<option value="Oman">Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau">Palau</option>
<option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
<option value="Panama">Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru">Peru</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
<option value="Poland">Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
<option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
<option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
<option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
<option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
<option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
<option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
<option value="Togo">Togo</option>
<option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
<option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
<option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
<option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
<option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<br>


<label>Email address</label><input name="email" type="email" size="45" /><br>

<label>Phone Number:</label><input name="phone" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>OOVOO:</label><input name="oovoo" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>SKYPE:</label><input name="skype" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>Fax:</label><input name="fax" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<label>Emergency Contact Number:</label><input name="emer_contact" type="text" size="45" /><br>

<div align="left" class="divider"><label><font style="color:red;">*</font>Age Group:</label><br> </div>
<input name="age_group" type="radio" value="Junior age (7 to 17)" /><label>Junior age (7 to 17)</label><br>
<input name="age_group" type="radio" value="Adult age (18 to 54)" /><label>Adult age (18 to 54)</label><br>
<input name="age_group" type="radio" value="Merlin (over 55)" /><label>Merlin (over 55)</label><br><br>


<div align="left" class="divider"><label>Deaf, Hard of Hearing? </label><br /></div>
<input name="deafHH" type="radio" value="Deaf" /><label>Deaf </label><br>
<input name="deafHH" type="radio" value="Hard of Hearing" /><label>Hard of Hearing</label><br><br>

<div align="left" class="divider">Hotel Room to be shared with (Magician, assistant or other person):</div><br />
<textarea name="room_contents" cols="85" rows="5">Names:</textarea><br><br>

<div align="center" class="agree">
I agree to abide to the Contest and Festival Organizers’ Rules. I confirm that I am a Deaf Magician.<br />
<input name="agree" type="radio" value="Agreed" />Yes<input name="agree" type="radio" value="Disagreed" />No<br><br>
</div>


<div align="center">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit_tourist" value="Send">
<input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset">
</div>



</div>







</div>
</div>
<div class="button_wrapper" align="center">
    <div class="buttons"><a href="index.html"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.home.png" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="buttons"><a href="world_wdmf_2014.html"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.wdmf2014.png" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="buttons"><a href="history.html"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.history.png" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="buttons"><a href="donations.html"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.donations.png" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="buttons"><a href="contact.php"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.contact.png" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="yellow-buttons">
<a href="magicians-applicant.php"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.applicants2.png" border="0" /></a>
<a href="#"><img class="button-image" src="images/button.deardeafhh2.png" border="0" /></a>
</div>
<div class="footer-bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I copied above and that messed up the CSS design on the site,but I see what you did. I will update the names of each textfields. I added the single quotes and it worked as it went through, but it ignored the blank textfields as if it didnt validate them before submit the form. I think it has to do with the _sendTouristapplicant.php